# .NET CF Windows Forms - 3 state push button

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, button

How to create a 3 state push button that behaves like check box but looks like normal button?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use a checkbox and change the Appareance property to "Button"

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the Button class and add your custom properties and logic to support a simple state engine to represent your 3 value states.